# Vuetify can't load default inside Vue-Toastification

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

What I'm trying to do is to use [vue-toastification](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification) with custom component inside the toast with some [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) components. I've created the repo using `npm create vuetify@latest` and installed the library `npm i vue-toastification@latest`. Then used the plugin:

```js
// main.ts

// Toastification
import Toast, { POSITION } from "vue-toastification";
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css";

const app = createApp(App);

const options = {
  shareAppContext: true, // From https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification#access-global-components-and-plugins-inside-toasts
  position: POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
};

registerPlugins(app);

app.use(Toast, options);
```

Then I try to call the toast with:

```js
// store/error.ts

import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";

const toast = useToast();

export const useErrorStore = defineStore("error", () => {
  function locationError() {
    toast(MyComponent);
  }
});
```

And inside my Component:

```js
// components/MyComponent.vue

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col> Alert example </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn @click="reload">Reload</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function reload() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
</script>
```

I call it from my App.vue file:

```js
// App.vue

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn @click="loc">Location Error</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useErrorStore } from "./store/error";

const errorStore = useErrorStore();

function loc() {
  errorStore.locationError();
}
</script>
```

But at runtime, when I click on the button, I get following errors:

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(vuetify:defaults)" not found. 
  at <VContainer> 
  at <MyComponent key=1 toast-id=0 onCloseToast=fn<bound closeToast> > 
  at <VtToast key="_default00" position="bottom-center" draggable=true  ... > 
  at <TransitionGroup tag="div" enter-active-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-enter-active" move-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-move"  ... > 
  at <VtTransition transition="Vue-Toastification__bounce" class="Vue-Toastification__container bottom-center" > 
  at <VueToastification eventBus= EventBus {allHandlers: {…}} shareAppContext= {_uid: 0, _component: {…}, _props: null, _container: div#app, _context: {…}, …} position="bottom-center" >

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <VContainer> 
  at <MyComponent key=1 toast-id=0 onCloseToast=fn<bound closeToast> > 
  at <VtToast key="_default00" position="bottom-center" draggable=true  ... > 
  at <TransitionGroup tag="div" enter-active-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-enter-active" move-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-move"  ... > 
  at <VtTransition transition="Vue-Toastification__bounce" class="Vue-Toastification__container bottom-center" > 
  at <VueToastification eventBus= EventBus {allHandlers: {…}} shareAppContext= {_uid: 0, _component: {…}, _props: null, _container: div#app, _context: {…}, …} position="bottom-center" >

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <VContainer> 
  at <MyComponent key=1 toast-id=0 onCloseToast=fn<bound closeToast> > 
  at <VtToast key="_default00" position="bottom-center" draggable=true  ... > 
  at <TransitionGroup tag="div" enter-active-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-enter-active" move-class="Vue-Toastification__bounce-move"  ... > 
  at <VtTransition transition="Vue-Toastification__bounce" class="Vue-Toastification__container bottom-center" > 
  at <VueToastification eventBus= EventBus {allHandlers: {…}} shareAppContext= {_uid: 0, _component: {…}, _props: null, _container: div#app, _context: {…}, …} position="bottom-center" >

Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Vuetify] Could not find defaults instance
    at injectDefaults (defaults.ts:28:24)
    at setup (defineComponent.tsx:118:24)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158:18)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7236:25)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7197:36)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5599:7)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565:9)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040:11)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284:7)
    at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191:7)
```

What I'm missing? Is impossible to get Vuetify working inside a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) loaded at runtime?

I've created an example repo [here](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/vuetify-vue-toastification-integration-issue).

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify components have to be wrapped inside the VApp element.
By default the vue toastification container is appended to the HTML body (making it a sibling of the VApp container).
To fix this issue you can add the following code when installing the vue toastification plugin:

```
import Toast from "vue-toastification";
import type { PluginOptions } from "vue-toastification";

const ToastOptions: PluginOptions = {
  shareAppContext: true,
  container: () => document.getElementById("app")!,
};

app.use(Toast, ToastOptions);
```

Container is the element where the toast should be mounted: HTMLElement or function that returns/resolves into an HTMLElement.
The Vuetify App element should be a div with id #app

To get access to other global plugins which you might use in the component for example $t from i18n, you might also want to access the app context. This can be done by adding the shareAppContext option. [more info](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification#access-global-components-and-plugins-inside-toasts)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but it doesn't work yet. I've tried to mount the toast inside `<div id="app"></div>`, `<v-app id="vuetify-app">` and `<v-main id="vuetify-main">`  every time failing. (using `container: () => document.getElementById("app")!,` and replacing "app" with "vuetify-app" or "vuetify-main"). I update the repo with a new commit with my attempts [here](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/vuetify-vue-toastification-integration-issue/commit/96f6912).